# How to create a pool for worker threads

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have been learning about the experimental [worker threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html) module in Node.js. I've read the official documentation, as well as most available articles, which are still quite sparse.

I have created a simple example that spawns ten (10) Worker threads in order to generate 10,000 SHA256 digests and then digitally sign them.

Using ten (10) Workers takes around two (2) seconds to generate all 10,000. Without workers, it takes approximately fifteen (15) seconds.

In the official documentation, it states that creating a pool of Workers is recommended versus spawning Workers on demand.

I've tried to find articles on how I'd go about doing this, but I haven't had any luck thus far.

How would I create a pool of Worker threads? Would the worker.js file somehow be modified so that I could create the Workers in advance and then send a message to the workers, which would cause them to execute their code? Would the pool be specific to the use case or is it possible to create a generic pool that could load a file or something and handle any use case?

Thank you.

**MAIN**

```
const { performance } = require('perf_hooks')
const { Worker } = require('worker_threads')        

// Spawn worker
const spawn = function spawnWorker(workerData) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const worker = new Worker('./worker.js', { workerData })
    worker.on('message', (message) => resolve(message))
    worker.on('error', reject)
    worker.on('exit', (code) => {
      if (code !== 0)
        reject(new Error(`Worker stopped with exit code ${code}`))
    })
  })
}

const generate = async function generateData() {
  const t0 = performance.now()
  const initArray = []
  for (step = 1; step < 10000; step += 1000) {
    initArray.push({
      start: step,
      end: step + 999
    })
  }
  const workersArray = initArray
    .map(x => spawn(x))
  const result = await Promise.all(workersArray)

  let finalArray = []
  for (let x of result) {
    finalArray = finalArray.concat(x.data)
  }
  const t1 = performance.now()
  console.log(`Total time: ${t1 - t0} ms`)
  console.log('Length:', finalArray.length)
}

generate()
  .then(x => {
    console.log('EXITING!')
    process.exit(0)
  })
```

**WORKERS**

```
const { performance } = require('perf_hooks')
const { workerData, parentPort, threadId} = require('worker_threads')
const crypto = require('crypto')
const keys =  require('./keys')

const hash = function createHash(data) {
  const result = crypto.createHash('sha256')
  result.update(data, 'utf8')
  return result.digest('hex')
}

const sign = function signData(key, data) {
  const result = crypto.createSign('RSA-SHA256')
  result.update(data)
  return result.sign(key, 'base64')
}

const t0 = performance.now()
const data = []
for (i = workerData.start; i <= workerData.end; i++) {
  const digest = hash(i.toString())
  const signature = sign(keys.HTTPPrivateKey, digest)
  data.push({
    id: i,
    digest,
    signature,
  })
}
const t1 = performance.now()

parentPort.postMessage({
  workerData,
  data,
  time: t1 - t0,
  status: 'Done',
 })
```

Comment: All that research and not a single mention of [Cluster](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_how_it_works).

Comment: @RandyCasburn I'm not sure what the purpose of your comment is. cluster/child processes are not the same as worker threads.

Comment: When I read your question what I saw was "_I want to run the exact same code in a worker thread_" and I didn't see the part about different files and controlling them independently. At any rate, I'm a bit curious about the performance of Cluster in the scene you've painted with this code. If you get a chance, grab the Clustered version of your code and benchmark it in the same environment as the others: https://repl.it/@randycasburn/NodeClusterCrypto

Comment: Oh, and here is a generic version of a pool implemenation: https://github.com/watson/worker-threads-pool

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [workerpool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/workerpool). It basically does all the pool management for you and it supports both worker threads and clusters.